# How to access data variable in page to control div in layout file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm building a simple Nuxt JS application using Vuetify. I have my layout setup as `default.vue` and I have a navbar within this file, I have a `<div>` within my navbar which is essentially an icon button, I'd like to be able to show/hide and access this div and control it from a page, e.g: `index.vue` within the pages/ directory.

Id like to have a variable such as: `isShown: true` and then add a `v-if="isShown"` to my div, however as it's in a layout it doesn't work.

Comment: You can just use vuex store

Answer (score 1):

One solution that may be familiar to you is to have one single source of truth `isShown` in the *store* that you can easily share between *layout/default.vue* and *pages/index.vue*

An other solution can rely on a [global event bus](https://medium.com/@Shardik/eventbus-for-nuxt-js-components-46660ae54f2d), but honestly even if you can resolve this problem with it, it is not necessary to use.